# pandas to_sql fails when using if_exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use the if_exists pandas to_sql arguments with sqlalchemy and i cannot seem to get it to work

#### versions

- sqlalchemy version 1.2.12
- pandas version 0.23.4
- python 3.5.2

  ```
  engine = create_engine(postgress_connection_string, echo=True)
  df1 = pd.DataFrame([['Abe','1','True'],['Ben','2','True'],['Charlie','3','True']], columns=['Name','Number','Other'])

  df1.to_sql('df_tbl',engine) #works if table doesn't exist, else fails
  df1.to_sql('df_tbl',engine, if_exists='replace') #fails with error message
  ```

> error: AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute '_engine'

### debug output

> > --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> >     last)  in 
> >           7 df_rides_stops.rename(index=str, columns={'orig_ad_id':'ad_id',
> >     'orig_stay_time':'stay_time','orig_arrival_utc':'arrival_utc'},inplace=True)
> >           8 df_rides_stops.head()
> >     ----> 9 df_rides_stops.to_sql('rides',engine, if_exists='replace')
> >          10
>
> ~/dev/Ride/qgis3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in
>   to_sql(self, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label,
>   chunksize, dtype)    2128         sql.to_sql(self, name, con,
>   schema=schema, if_exists=if_exists,    2129
>   index=index, index_label=index_label, chunksize=chunksize,
>   -> 2130                    dtype=dtype)    2131     2132     def to_pickle(self, path, compression='infer',
>
> ~/dev/Ride/qgis3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in
>   to_sql(frame, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label,
>   chunksize, dtype)
>       448     pandas_sql.to_sql(frame, name, if_exists=if_exists, index=index,
>       449                       index_label=index_label, schema=schema,
>   --> 450                       chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
>       451 
>       452
>
> ~/dev/Ride/qgis3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in
>   to_sql(self, frame, name, if_exists, index, index_label, schema,
>   chunksize, dtype)    1124
>   if_exists=if_exists, index_label=index_label,    1125
>   schema=schema, dtype=dtype)
>   -> 1126         table.create()    1127         table.insert(chunksize)    1128         if (not name.isdigit() and not name.islower()):
>
> ~/dev/Ride/qgis3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in
>   create(self)
>       563                 raise ValueError("Table '%s' already exists." % self.name)
>       564             elif self.if_exists == 'replace':
>   --> 565                 self.pd_sql.drop_table(self.name, self.schema)
>       566                 self._execute_create()
>       567             elif self.if_exists == 'append':
>
> ~/dev/Ride/qgis3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in
>   drop_table(self, table_name, schema)    1173         schema = schema
>   or self.meta.schema    1174         if self.has_table(table_name,
>   schema):
>   -> 1175             self.meta.reflect(only=[table_name], schema=schema)    1176             self.get_table(table_name,
>   schema).drop()    1177             self.meta.clear()
>
> ~/dev/Ride/qgis3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py
>   in reflect(self, bind, schema, views, only, extend_existing,
>   autoload_replace, **dialect_kwargs)    3961             for name in
>   load:    3962                 try:
>   -> 3963                     Table(name, self, **reflect_opts)    3964                 except exc.UnreflectableTableError as uerr:    3965
>   util.warn("Skipping table %s: %s" % (name, uerr))
>
> ~/dev/Ride/qgis3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py
>   in **new**(cls, *args, **kw)
>       455             except:
>       456                 with util.safe_reraise():
>   --> 457                     metadata._remove_table(name, schema)
>       458 
>       459     @property
>
> ~/dev/Ride/qgis3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py
>   in **exit**(self, type_, value, traceback)
>        64             self._exc_info = None   # remove potential circular references
>        65             if not self.warn_only:
>   ---> 66                 compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
>        67         else:
>        68             if not compat.py3k and self._exc_info and self._exc_info[1]:
>
> ~/dev/Ride/qgis3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py
>   in reraise(tp, value, tb, cause)
>       247         if value.**traceback** is not tb:
>       248             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
>   --> 249         raise value
>       250 
>       251 else:
>
> ~/dev/Ride/qgis3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py
>   in **new**(cls, *args, **kw)
>       450             metadata._add_table(name, schema, table)
>       451             try:
>   --> 452                 table._init(name, metadata, *args, **kw)
>       453                 table.dispatch.after_parent_attach(table, metadata)
>       454                 return table
>
> ~/dev/Ride/qgis3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py
>   in _init(self, name, metadata, *args, **kwargs)
>       532             self._autoload(
>       533                 metadata, autoload_with,
>   --> 534                 include_columns, _extend_on=_extend_on)
>       535 
>       536         # initialize all the column, etc. objects.  done after reflection to
>
> ~/dev/Ride/qgis3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py
>   in _autoload(self, metadata, autoload_with, include_columns,
>   exclude_columns, _extend_on)
>       545                 autoload_with.dialect.reflecttable,
>       546                 self, include_columns, exclude_columns,
>   --> 547                 _extend_on=_extend_on
>       548             )
>       549         else:
>
> ~/dev/Ride/qgis3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py
>   in run_callable(self, callable_, *args, **kwargs)    1543     1544
>   """
>   -> 1545         return callable_(self, *args, **kwargs)    1546     1547     def _run_visitor(self, visitorcallable, element, **kwargs):
>
> ~/dev/Ride/qgis3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py
>   in reflecttable(self, connection, table, include_columns,
>   exclude_columns, **opts)
>       387     def reflecttable(
>       388             self, connection, table, include_columns, exclude_columns, **opts):
>   --> 389         insp = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(connection)
>       390         return insp.reflecttable(
>       391             table, include_columns, exclude_columns, **opts)
>
> ~/dev/Ride/qgis3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py
>   in from_engine(cls, bind)
>       132         """
>       133         if hasattr(bind.dialect, 'inspector'):
>   --> 134             return bind.dialect.inspector(bind)
>       135         return Inspector(bind)
>       136
>
> ~/dev/Ride/qgis3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/base.py
>   in **init**(self, conn)    2026     2027     def **init**(self, conn):
>   -> 2028         reflection.Inspector.**init**(self, conn)    2029     2030     def get_table_oid(self, table_name, schema=None):
>
> ~/dev/Ride/qgis3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py
>   in **init**(self, bind)
>       101         # set the engine
>       102         if hasattr(bind, 'engine'):
>   --> 103             self.engine = bind._engine
>       104         else:
>       105             self.engine = bind
>
> AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute '_engine'

Comment: if you're using the default schema this won't be an issue, the replace parameter raises an error on different schema because the DROP goes directyl to the default schema, the solution is to add {schema=' your_schema'}

Answer (score 1):

From [`pandas.DataFrame.to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) one can see that one should pass the type of connection as `con=engine` (or `con=connection`) and not just `engine` (and the error seems to point to that). The following should work

```
df1.to_sql('df_tbl',con=engine, if_exists='replace')
```

For future reference, one might consider checking other examples in the documentation page (assuming it has). For this particular case it is [this one](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html).